# Prove that sequence diverges by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can you help me to prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} (n-2n^2)= -\infty $ given definition $\forall \varepsilon>0  \  \exists N  \in  \mathbb{N}: n \geq N \Rightarrow  \left | x_n -a \right |< \varepsilon$. As far as I know, I have to use necessity and sufficienty, but I don't know how to construct the proof.

Comment: In the limit, shouldn't be there $n$ instead of $x$ ?

Comment: Formally it must be proved that:

$$\forall r\in\mathbb R\exists N\in\mathbb N\forall n\geq N [n-2n^2<r]$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : If $n>1$, $$n-2n^2<-n^2.$$

If $M<0$, taking $N>\sqrt{-M}$ make the job.

---

Notice that $\lim_{n\to \infty }f(n)=-\infty $ if $$\forall M<0,\exists N\in\mathbb N: \forall n\in\mathbb N, n\geq N\implies f(n)<M.$$

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your help but can you expand the explanation a little?

Comment: @programming_undergraduate_1: If $n\geq N$, then $n-2n^2<-n^2<-\sqrt{-M}^2=M.$